# Mule with https inbound fails to invoke amqp

Tags: https, rabbitmq, mule, amqp

I have setup rabbitMQ and created application with http inbound.

```
<flow>
<http:inbound />
<amqp:outbound ../>
</flow>
```

the above flow works perfectly. but when i switch to https:inbound it get fails  with error message 'invalid value in table'

```
<flow>
<https:inbound />
<amqp:outbound ../>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For workaround, remove outbound property - LOCAL_CERTIFICATE before calling amqp.

Comment: Faced exactly the same issue. And this solution worked. Do you have any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue however there is no public issue yet, just an internal one (I´m the official maintainer).

This will be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Victor, Will it fixed from MULE side? which version. I am using 3.5.1 right now.

Comment: I'm unsure where it will be fixed yet, but it's likely to happen at the connector level. Sadly it won't be ready for the version 3.6 of the connector (still compatible with 3.5.1)